# A basic "Helper" program not working as expected

Tags: ruby, function, puts

I'm making a basic "Helper" program..
Anyway here's the code:

```
def sayHelp()

    puts "------------List of help and commands-------------" 
    puts "Help-- Shows a list of commands."
    puts "Start [PROGRAM] (PROGRAM ARGS)-- Starts the specified program." 
    return true
end    

version = "1.0"
ccommand = ""

puts "Welcome to RubyBot " + version + "."
puts "------------------------------------"
sleep(3)
system "clear" or system "cls"
puts "Enter \"help\" for a list of commands."


puts "Please enter a command: "
ccommand = gets


if ccommand == "help"
    sayHelp()
else
    puts "Not right bro"
end
```

I go ahead and run this and enter help but it just chucks `Not right bro` up at me.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read your question after you posted it?  Is it a complete mess?  You have to learn how to post code before you can ask a question.  In any case, anything entered on the command line will have a newline("\n") as the last character and "help\n" will never equal "help".  Try `gets.chomp`.

Comment: sorry, im still new to this and had some trouble formatting.. anyway i figured it out but thanks for your time :D

Comment: Ahhhh...the old `gets.chomp` question/answer.  FWIW: ruby methods should be in [`snake_case`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars), and the empty parens aren't needed if there are no method parameters.

Comment: By the way, if you want to see what's actually in a string, use the command: `p ccommand`.  In fact, try that before changing to `gets.chomp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ccommand = gets
```

The string returned by `gets` has a trailing new line character, remove it and it will work:

```
ccommand = gets.chomp
```